# Equivalence relation - function

Tags: equivalence-relations

Put a relation on $C[0,1]$ by $f\sim g$ if $f(k/10)=g(k/10)$ for $k$ with $0\le k \le10$

I have shown that this is an equivalence relation, but I have no idea what are the equivalence classes. It requires me to prove together with addition of eq class and scalar multiplication, it makes $C[0,1]/\sim$ into a vector space of dimension 11.

So I guess I have something to do with $k/10$. Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: $k\in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti It doesn't say anything on $k$, is there any difference if $k \in \Bbb Z$ and $k \notin \Bbb Z$ ?

Comment: Is it  $\forall\ k\in \mathbb Z\cap[0,10]$ or $\forall\ k\in \mathbb R\cap[0,10]$?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something

Comment: You didn't miss anything, the first line in this article is all the question have written down, it doesn't specify what is $k$. I find this question in the book called Real Analysis and Applications by Kenneth R. Davidson and Allan P. Donsig.